# Stuck in Bandit level 0. (overthewire.org)

Tags: linux, bash, zshrc, bandit

Unable to connect, And not sure how many ways I can type "bandit0" for a password
[image]

Answer (score 0):

ssh is not telnet with its general syntax of telnet server port. I believe even in Windows the basic usage of ssh is like:

```
ssh [-p port] [user@]server [command]
```

You did ssh bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org 2220. You connected to the default port (22) and 2220 was the command.

It so happens there is a server on port 22, but this is not the server that accepts the credentials you know.

The command 2220 was never invoked because you failed to authenticate in the first place. Instead of 2220 it could have been anything, it wouldn't be invoked either.

You want to connect like this:

```
ssh -p 2220 bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, my connection times out without asking for a password. Is bandit still alive?

Comment: Switching to a different network allowed me to solve bandit0. It's probably some sort of network setting I will have to look into.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have this problem "Too many authentication failures", use this:

```
ssh bandit0@bandit.labs.overthewire.org -p 2220
```

if you are a windows user, it is better to use **PuTTY** than cmd.exe to play this game:

> host name: bandit.labs.overthewire.org
>
> port: 2220
>
> open

> login as: bandit0
>
> password: bandit0
>
> done

---

- **[Bandit](https://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/)**